# C# List without Elements of another List (set theory, complement)

Tags: c#, list

I got two `List<Image>` (`ListA` and `ListB`) and i need an efficient way to get the elements of `ListA` without the elements of `ListB` (A\B)

For example:

- `ListA` contains `Image1`, `Image2`, `Image3`, `Image4`
- `ListB`    contains `Image2`, `Image4`
- `ListA` \ `ListB` would be `Image1`,    `Image3`

I'm relatively new to C# and open for some suggestions

Comment: `var result = ListA.Except(ListB).ToList();`

Comment: You may be missing a previous search, this question is [likely duplicated](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+list+except)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If items of `ListA` are *unique* you can put a simple *Linq* query:

```
  using System.Linq;

  ...

  List<Image> result = ListA
    .Except(ListB)
    .ToList();
```

If you want to modify *existing* list (i.e. `ListA`):

```
  ListA.RemoveAll(image => ListB.Contains(image));
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I realised that i have to implement the IEquatable Interface to my custom Image class

Comment: @flexwend: well, yes, if you have to compare *different instances* which can be equal to one another (i.e. if `Image1` can be equal to `Image2`); in case images are equal if and only if they share the same *reference* you don't have to implement any `IEquatable<T>`